# How to load image from data resources in eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, image, resources

I have a file called "Resource" in my project, and a jpg imaged called "coffe.jpg".
I want to load it to 
Image image1;

but its not working! I am using this code, it returns NULL:

```
try { 
    image1=ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/../../Resource/coffe.jpg"));   
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have tried this one also: same NULL:

```
image1=java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(getClass().getResource("/Resource/coffe.jpg"));
```

Comment: The resource is not a package.

Comment: In which Java package is the image located?

Comment: its in folder, not package. oh so this is the prob. why?

Comment: getClass().getResource() loads resources using the class loader, from a directory or jar that is in the classpath, and taking a package path as argument. Read the javadoc. To load an image from a file on the file system, use file IO.

Comment: @AtheelMassalha Resources should be in a  sources folder to be included on the classpath along with other classed of the compiler output.

Comment: getResource() looks for a resource _in the classpath_.  That the classpath happens for this resource to be files in a folder does not mean that you should not think of it as a thing in your classpath.  In other words, you need a source folder and a suitable path inside that source folder.

Comment: ok thanks every one it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

the path is most likely relative so the / is throwing it off.

Try getResourceStream if you are loading it from a .jar or package

```
 this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/coffe.jpg");
```

or try the path without the leading "/"

```
 this.getClass().getResource("coffe.jpg");
```